# SQL trigger for updating a table

Tags: sql-server, triggers, sql-server-2012

I have 3 tables as follows:

- `ticket`: ID, Note
- `action`: ID, date, ticket_ID, type
- `action_type`: ID, type, name

Every time a new record is being inserted into `action`, I need to concatenate `ticket.Note` with `action.date` and `action_type.name`. But only in case of certain action types.

So take the following situation:

- `ticket`  is: 0056, someNote
- `action` is: 001234, 06/30/2015 14:00:22, 0056, 4
- `action_type` is: 004, 4, create

I need `#0056` `ticket.Note` to be `someNote;06-30-2015 create`

I tried the code below, but I get `incorrect syntax` error:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_notes
ON action
AFTER INSERT AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE ticket
    SET
    Note = 
        Note + 
        ';' + 
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),(select date from inserted),110) + 
        (select 
             t.name 
         from 
             action_type t 
         LEFT OUTER JOIN inserted i ON i.action = t.ID 
         WHERE 
             i.action = t.ID)
    where 
        ticket.ID = inserted.ticket_ID
    AND 
        (inserted.action = 4 
         OR 
         inserted.action = 7 
         OR 
         inserted.action = 8 
         OR 
         inserted.action = 11 
         OR 
         inserted.action = 12)
END
```

Comment: since `inserted`is a table with possibly many rows, your syntax makes no sense.

Comment: @SQLPolice Probably the solution is crap as much as your comment. At least tell me why you think it's crap...

Comment: Then why did you comment at first place? You added no value whatsoever.

Comment: It begins with the fact that you are using hard-coded values (so-called *literals*) in your trigger. think of how you could replace them with a more generic concept, and then you get near a much better solution.

Comment: @SQLPolice +1 for advicing correct beviour :)

Comment: revenge-downvotes? What the heck are you talking about?

Comment: You are paranoid. And therefore I don't think the system is dumb but you. I did not downvote anything since Dec last year. http://i.imgur.com/ydYnsTW.png

Comment: 1. I just don't like you accusation here. Get an admin and find out the truth.
2. I do need notes, cause other users can put any kind of note in it.

Comment: @fishmong3r I edited your question so your names are consistent (`Notes`/`Note`, `action_typ`/`action_type`), and it is better formatted. I then removed the downvote. My opinion however is still the same. Your design is not good, you could do much better without triggers. But the question itself is legitim.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you want to achieve is this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_notes
ON action
AFTER INSERT AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE  t
    SET     t.Note = t.Note + ';' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),i.[date],110) + at.name
    FROM    inserted i
            inner join tickets t ON i.ticket_ID = t.ID
            inner join action_type at ON i.[type] = at.[type]
    WHERE   inserted.[type] IN(4,7,8,11,12) 
END
```

Comment: This is just not working. The ticket is not updating on action insert.

Comment: i tried with you sample data - works! so why the downvote?

Comment: this IS working. unless data in `tickets` and `action_typ` table exist BEFORE you insert into `action`

Comment: The downvote wasn't me. So of course the `ticket` and `action_typ` data exist BEFORE the insert action. I have tickets and actions related to them. No action can exist without a ticket.